# GPG Hangs When Private Keys are Accessed

Tags: git, gpg, pgp, openpgp

I like to sign my git commits with my PGP key, so I was quite alarmed when I went to `git commit -S` but instead of prompting for my PGP key passphrase, git just started hanging. I haven't made a change to my GPG setup in several months and have made many commits since then with no problem. Additionally, when I attempt to view my private keys with `gpg -K`, gpg hangs. However, when I run `gpg -k` to view my public keys, it returns the list like normal. Hopefully someone will have some idea of what is causing this problem and how to fix it.

Comment: are you doing this over ssh?  if so, do you have `gpg-agent` or similar setup in the .bashrc (etc) of the remote system, and configured to prompt on the remote's X display or similar?  i've had similar problems in the past (e.g. ssh-ing from a terminal on my mythtv box to my desktop machine to run something requiring gpg.  also had similar issues with `ssh-agent`), and i brute-force "fixed" it with `export GPG_TTY=$(tty)` in the .bashrc, to make sure the prompt is always on the current tty.  i can't stand GUI passwd prompts anyway.

Comment: No, I'm not doing it over SSH. What's weird is that I found that if I kill gpg-agent, gpg works again. I'm trying to figure out why and make a long term solution.

Comment: I just noticed in the `gpg-agent` man page that setting GPG_TTY as above isn't something I hacked up to work, it's required.  The man page says you should always set it in your .bashrc as I did, and also says `It is important that this environment variable always reflects the output of the  tty  command.` - that must have been where I got it from.  One other thing you need to be careful of is the pinentry program used by gpg-agent.  I have mine set (in `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`) to `/usr/bin/pinentry-curses`

Answer (score 42):

I came across this exact issue (OSX Sierra 10.12.6, gpg/GnuPG 2.2.5)

Commands that would hang:

```
gpg -K # --list-secret-keys
gpg -d # --decrypt
gpg --edit-key
gpgconf --kill gpg-agent
```

My solution was the same as mentioned by [John](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/177537/john-leuenhagen) above (ie. kill gpg-agent) as most other methods on [how-can-i-restart-gpg-agent](https://superuser.com/questions/1075404/how-can-i-restart-gpg-agent) would also hang.

```
# Solution    
pkill -9 gpg-agent
```

Then for signing git commits I set the tty env as mentioned by [cas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/7696/cas) above and also at [gpg-failed-to-sign-commit-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39494631/gpg-failed-to-sign-the-data-fatal-failed-to-write-commit-object-git-2-10-0/42265848#42265848).

```
export GPG_TTY=$(tty)
```

Comment: So do you have to re-kill gpg every time you reboot? That's what I've been having to do for a long time now. I hope we'll find a way to fix it for good.

Comment: Just started having the issue myself. Killing the `gpg-agent` seems to be the only way to get it working again.

Comment: Got this issue on Ubuntu 22.04, and it persists even after killing `gpg-agent`.

Comment: Found a working solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53641081/1708426

Comment: When I kill `gpg-agent` in a Visual Studio Code devcontainer, it comes right back.

Answer (score -1):

```bsh
$ ps aux | grep -E "gpg-agent"
alper  28970   0.0   92436   3284   15:31 0:00 /usr/bin/gpg-agent --supervised
```

Here output variable contains `28970`.

---

```py
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import signal

def kill_process_by_name(process_name):
    p1 = Popen(["ps", "auxww"], stdout=PIPE)
    p2 = Popen(["grep", "-E", process_name], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
    p1.stdout.close()  # noqa
    p3 = Popen(["awk", "{print $2}"], stdin=p2.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
    p2.stdout.close()
    output = p3.communicate()[0].decode("utf-8").strip()
    lines = output.splitlines()  # awk may return more than one pid number
    for pid in lines:
        if pid.isnumeric():
            os.kill(int(pid), signal.SIGKILL)
```

Comment: This isn't really a solution to the problem, just a workaround. I'd advise against auto-killing processes in a script like this.

Comment: Why are you against auto-killing processes in a script like this? Wouldn't you kill processes in a bash-script using `kill -9 $(ps auxww | grep -E "[p]rocess_name" | awk '{print $2}') > /dev/null 2>&1`?

Comment: that would be just as bad. My point is that automatically killing a process to get it to work isn't a solution. It's just an ugly workaround, and I wouldn't feel comfortable using it.

Comment: What would you fell comfortable to use? Don't you ever automatically  kill a process and restart it in your on computer, or ever restart the operating system if somehing unexpected happens?