# gpg-agent hanging when trying to access private keys

Tags: debian, systemd, gpg, gpg-agent, systemd-unit

I'm having trouble using `gpg` (actually, the `gpg-agent`) on my `Debian Bullseye (Stable)` system.  More precisely, I use the following:

```
gpg --version | head -n2
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.27
libgcrypt 1.8.8

uname -v
#1 SMP Debian 5.10.46-4 (2021-08-03)

lsb_release -a 2> /dev/null
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
Release:    11
Codename:   bullseye
```

I haven't rebooted my machine for approx 3 months.  During that time I was able to use `gpg` without difficulties (encrypting, decrypting, signing, verifying, key management).  I made multiple updates during the last months, none of which created any problems for me (in addition I'm using `needrestart`).  I didn't change anything in the relevant config files (I know of, being `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf`, `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`, `~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf`) in the last 3 months.

Today I restarted my machine and suddenly I wasn't able to use my `gpg-agent` for anything, where secret keys are involved.  While `gpg -k [1]` and `gpg --search-keys DEADBEEF` lead to results, `gpg -K` as well as `gpg -d /PATH/TO/ENCRYPTED/FILE` hangs indefinitely.  Similarly, `gpg-connect-agent reloadagent /bye` and `gpgconf --kill gpg-agent` as well as `systemctl --user start gpg-agent` leads to hanging.  Similarly, my systemd-unit-file is not out of the ordenary:

```
systemctl --user cat gpg-agent | grep -Ev '^#|^$'
[Unit]
Description     = gpg-agent (password store for gpg-keys)
[Service]
Type            = forking
ExecStart       = /usr/bin/gpg-agent --daemon
ExecStop        = /usr/bin/gpg-connect-agent /bye
Restart         = on-abort
[Install]
WantedBy        = default.target
```

I'm aware that this problem has already been described by others (see e.g. [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/382279/gpg-hangs-when-private-keys-are-accessed) but the mentioned solution (`pkill -9 gpg-agent`) does not apply to me, since this is happening eventhough no other process containing the string `gpg` (read: the `gpg-agent`) is running.

```
ps -ef | grep gpg && echo " " && gpg --verbose --debug-level guru -K
MYUSERNAME     59248 59247  0 17:17 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto gpg
 
gpg: enabled debug flags: packet mpi crypto filter iobuf memory cache memstat trust hashing ipc clock lookup extprog
gpg: DBG: [not enabled in the source] start
gpg: DBG: [not enabled in the source] keydb_new
gpg: DBG: [not enabled in the source] keydb_search_reset
gpg: DBG: keydb_search: reset  (hd=0x000055c04a474cd0)
gpg: DBG: [not enabled in the source] keydb_search enter
gpg: DBG: keydb_search: 1 search descriptions:
gpg: DBG: keydb_search   0: FIRST
gpg: DBG: keydb_search: searching keybox (resource 0 of 1)
gpg: DBG: keydb_search: searched keybox (resource 0 of 1) => Success
gpg: DBG: [not enabled in the source] keydb_search leave (found)
gpg: DBG: [not enabled in the source] keydb_get_keybock enter
gpg: DBG: parse_packet(iob=1): type=6 length=51 (parse.../../g10/keydb.c.1242)
gpg: DBG: parse_packet(iob=1): type=12 length=12 (parse.../../g10/keydb.c.1242)
gpg: DBG: parse_packet(iob=1): type=13 length=19 (parse.../../g10/keydb.c.1242)
gpg: DBG: parse_packet(iob=1): type=12 length=12 (parse.../../g10/keydb.c.1242)
gpg: DBG: parse_packet(iob=1): type=2 length=150 (parse.../../g10/keydb.c.1242)
gpg: DBG: parse_packet(iob=1): type=12 length=6 (parse.../../g10/keydb.c.1242)
gpg: DBG: parse_packet(iob=1): type=2 length=150 (parse.../../g10/keydb.c.1242)
gpg: DBG: parse_packet(iob=1): type=12 length=6 (parse.../../g10/keydb.c.1242)
gpg: DBG: parse_packet(iob=1): type=14 length=56 (parse.../../g10/keydb.c.1242)
gpg: DBG: parse_packet(iob=1): type=2 length=126 (parse.../../g10/keydb.c.1242)
gpg: DBG: parse_packet(iob=1): type=12 length=6 (parse.../../g10/keydb.c.1242)
gpg: DBG: parse_packet(iob=1): type=14 length=51 (parse.../../g10/keydb.c.1242)
gpg: DBG: parse_packet(iob=1): type=2 length=245 (parse.../../g10/keydb.c.1242)
gpg: DBG: parse_packet(iob=1): type=12 length=6 (parse.../../g10/keydb.c.1242)
gpg: DBG: iobuf-1.0: underflow: buffer size: 924; still buffered: 0 => space for 924 bytes
gpg: DBG: iobuf-1.0: close '?'

<<< HERE HANGING INDEFINITELY >>>

^C
gpg: signal Interrupt caught ... exiting
```

Also my variables GPG_AGENT_INFO and GPG_TTY are set.

```
echo -e "$GPG_AGENT_INFO\n$GPG_TTY"
/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1
/dev/pts/1
```

Rebooting btw. didn't change anything. Any ideas?

---

edit1: reinstalling `gpg`, `gpg-agent` and `dirmngr` doesn't fix the issue.  Additionally, removing the files `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf`, `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` and `~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf` doesn't solve it.

---

edit2: in the meantime I upgraded from `PureOS Amber` to `Debian Stable (Bullseye)` and reinstalled a new version of `gpg`, `gpg-agent`, `dirmngr` and `libgcrypt20` (and changed the text above to reflect the new version), but the problem is still present.

---

[1] technically speaking `gpg -k` also hung, but I assume this was because I enabeled the option `with-secret` in my `gpg.conf`-file.  After commenting that out this problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution, although I'm not sure I understand it.

Somehow the version of `gpg-agent` started by `systemd` was the issue.  When performing `systemctl --user mask gpg-agent` and then restarting the `gpg-agent` manually, the problem disappeared.  I'll try to understand why that was the case and then write an update here.

Comment: What are the `Private*` and `Protect*` rules in the SystemD unit file(s)?

Comment: @xebeche: I'm unfamiliar with those terms, what exactly to you mean?  I masked the `gpg-agent` systemd-service, the other ones relevant for working with gpg don't have that string present (when running `systemctl --user cat gpg* | grep -E -i 'private|protect'` I don't get any output).

Comment: So my guess was wrong. About `Private*` etc. see e.g. [systemd.exec(5)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html)

Answer (score 0):

Usually if you `reinstall gnupg`, the problem will be solved. Unless the cause of the problem is something else.

Comment: I'm afraid that wasn't it - after running ` sudo apt install --reinstall gpg gpg-agent dirmngr` with a subsequent `killall -9 gpg2 gpg-agent` the command `gpg -K` still hangs.